# How to name pandas dataframe column based on the column contents

Tags: python, pandas

I have this text file that I have to load up into a pandas dataframe. On loading the text, I discovered there are no column names. There are about 23 columns and the content of each column are different letters of the English alphabet. I want to rename each column based on which alphabets are in the column. For example, if 's', 'b', 'd' and 'f' are in column 1, i want to rename it 'CapSize' and if 's', 'r', 'g', 'f' and 'k' are in column 2 I like to give it the name 'Root'.

I tried something like this but no way out.

```
for i in range(23):
  if (X.columns[0] == 'b' & X.columns[0] == 'c' & X.columns[0] == 'x'&     X.columns[0] == 'f' &  X.columns[0] == 'k' & X.columns[0] == 's'):
    X.columns[0] = 'Capshape'
     print X.columns[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I get your question right, since letter 's' are both in CapSize and root, and do you mean it has to be conditional for each column separately?

Otherwise, if I get it correctly it is something like this:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({0:['fb', 'bc'], 1:['baab', 'cbc'], 2:['kaab', 'cbc']})
dt


0   1   2
0   fb  baab    kaab
1   bc  cbc cbc
```

Get first letters into pd.Series

```
letters = pd.Series(dt.apply(lambda x: x.head(1).map(lambda y: y[0])).loc[0,:].values)
letters

0    f
1    b
2    k
dtype: object
```

Create a dict for mapping

```
mp = {x:'CapSize' for x in ['s', 'b', 'd' , 'f'] }
mp.update({x:'Root' for x in [ 'r', 'g', 'f' , 'k']})
mp

{'b': 'CapSize',
 'd': 'CapSize',
 'f': 'Root',
 'g': 'Root',
 'k': 'Root',
 'r': 'Root',
 's': 'CapSize'}
```

Map first letters using a dict

```
letters = letters.map(mp).tolist()
letters

['Root', 'CapSize', 'Root']

dt.columns  = letters

dt


Root    CapSize Root
0   fb  baab    kaab
1   bc  cbc cbc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it with *.issibset()* like this:

```
dic = {'CapSize':['s','b','d','f'], 'Root':['s','r','g','f','k']}

def col_name(letter_set):
 ...:     for key in dic.keys():
 ...:         if letter_set.issubset(dic[key]): return key 

df.columns = [col_name(set(df[column].str[0])) for column in df.columns]
```